# Reason for chroot failure: tmp-mksh: chroot: not found

Tags: shell, terminal, scripts, bash

**Introduction:**

I formatted a SDCard in ext4 and copied an ArchVersion on it to run it from Android like in this [guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mDYfvXy5NoDCWgHkIhm0VKyrDi6eYzUIXotxiWCxoG4/edit?pref=2&pli=1) (step 6). Of course my device is rooted and am running the following scripts and commands in the *Terminal Emulator* as superuser.

Device-info:

- Phone: Sony Xperia Z1
- Model number: C6903
- Android version: 5.1.1
- Build Number: 14.6.A.1.236

**Issue:**

When I execute `sh chroot_bashonly.sh` the error `tmp-mksh: chroot: not found` appears. Of course I looked in the script to figure it out myself:

***chroot_bashonly.sh:***

```
#!/bin/sh

export LINUXROOT=/data/local/mnt
export TMPDIR=/tmp
export HOME=/root
export USER=root
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:$PATH
export TERM=vt100


sh ./mount.sh

echo "******* Your chroot-environment is starting now ********"
chroot $LINUXROOT /bin/bash # tmp-mksh: chroot: not found
echo "******* You exited the chroot-environment, unmounting... ********"

sh ./umount.sh

echo " ## DONE"
```

***mount.sh:***

```
#!/bin/sh

export LINUXROOT=/data/local/mnt
export TMPDIR=/tmp
export HOME=/root
export USER=root
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:$PATH
export TERM=vt100

# mount /
mkdir $LINUXROOT #works
mount -t ext4 -o noatime,rw /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 $LINUXROOT #works

# mount other stuff
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/proc 
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/sys 
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/dev 
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/dev/pts 
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/var/lib/dbus
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/android_storage/sdcard0
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/android_storage/sdcard1
mkdir -p $LINUXROOT/system
mount -t proc proc $LINUXROOT/proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs $LINUXROOT/sys
mount -o bind /dev $LINUXROOT/dev 
mount -t devpts devpts $LINUXROOT/dev/pts
mount -o bind /system $LINUXROOT/system
mount -o bind /storage/sdcard0 $LINUXROOT/android_storage/sdcard0
mount -o bind /storage/sdcard1 $LINUXROOT/android_storage/sdcard1

echo "******* everything mounted ********"
```

I think the ***mount.sh*** part works, at least I get no error and the `mkdir`-created folders existing. So the next thing I tried was to run `chroot` outside the script in many forms with the same error.

1. `chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/bash`
2. `chroot /data/local/mnt /system/bin/sh`
3. `chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/sh`

All having the same issue: `tmp-mksh: chroot: not found`.

So what is wrong?

Is chroot even available on Android?

Comment: Try issuing `type chroot` or `whence -v chroot`, and tell us the result.

Comment: So I tried `type chroot /data/local/mnt /bin/bash`. Result (error): 1. `chroot not found`, 2. `/data/local/mnt not found` (but it exists), 3. `/bin/bash not found`.  I tried `type chroot /data/local/mnt /system/bin/sh`. Result (error): 1. *same*, 2. *same*, 3. `/system/bin/sh is /system/bin/sh`....      The  results for `whence -v chroot` are equivalent.

Comment: First and foremost, I said `type`, with one and only argument for it, which was `chroot`. Aside from that, you may need to install **BusyBox**, in order to be able to use **chroot**, since your device lacks it.

Comment: Thanks. I am a step forward. Now `type chroot` refers `chroot is /system/xbin/chroot`. But now I get the error `chroot: cant execute '/bin/bash': No such file or directory` or for */system/bin/sh* `chroot: cant execute '/system/bin/sh': No such file or directory`. Well I checked the */system/bin/sh* file. Like it is stated in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8095453/5233188) it is exisiting

Comment: As before, issue `type sh`: this will tell you the location of the shell binary, which you'll need to replace any instance of **/bin/bash** with.

Comment: `type sh` refers `sh is tracked alias for /system/bin/sh`, but like I stated before it says `No such file or directory`

Comment: It appears that we're going outside the scope of your question, which concerned **only chroot**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reason for this failure is that Android blocked **chroot** for som reason. Like [Death Mask Salesman](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/152843/death-mask-salesman) pointed out, it is possible to get information about the command type via [`type commandName`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/typeh.html) e.g. in this case `type chroot`.

To solve the `tmp-mksh: chroot: not found`-error it is only required to install [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=de).

Comment: i installed the busyBox but still the problem appear !!!

Comment: @user197885 With _installed_ you mean that you _installed_ busyBox out of the app store then started busyBox and _installed_ a version of busyBox to `/system/xbin` ?